# Trying to automatically change tab colors in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Background: I am working on a checklist project that has about 100 similar sheets. I have got it all working down to a summary table. If there is an unchecked box then it shows up on this summary section on the bottom of each sheet. There is a total row at the bottom of the summary section which basically shows the amount of unchecked items on the sheet.

SO, now to my question. If that cell has a value more than 0 then I want the tab color to be red. If it has a value of 0 then I want the tab color to be green for that sheet.

I have seen forums where people say that I should put my code under the Worksheet_Change function in the VBA editor for that sheet. BUT that won't work. I'll put code in there and it doesn't run. I was wondering if anyone knew where I was doing something wrong.

I have also tried to put the code in a module and calling it in the sheet code but that didn't work either. It seems like other people are having success with this kind of thing so I am sure I am just not thinking of something.

For Reference:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B104")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is > 0
            ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = 3 'red
        Case Is = 0
            ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = 4 'green
        Case Else
            ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = xlNone 'no color
    End Select
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If cell  **B10** contains a *formula*, then you must use the `Calculate` event rather than the `Change` event.

Comment: Also use `Me` in place of `ActiveSheet`

Comment: If you have multiple sheets which need this functionality, then use the `Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)` event in the `ThisWorkbook` module - then you don't need code in every sheet

Comment: Tim, I have changed it to me thanks for that. As far as the other comment, I do need it for all sheets except for 2 so I think I am screwed and will have to copy and paste it 100 times when I go and copy all the sheets. :(

Comment: Using the workbook event you can still filter out the two sheets you want to skip

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestion from Tim, and your logic...I would do something like this:

```
Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)

 If sh.name = "thatname" or sh.name = "anothername" then exit sub

      Select Case sh.Range("B104").Value
          Case Is > 0
                Sh.Tab.ColorIndex = 3 'red
          Case Is = 0
                Sh.Tab.ColorIndex = 4 'green
          Case Else
                Sh.Tab.ColorIndex = xlNone 'no color
     End Select
End Sub
```

Apologies for any indentation issues, posting from my phone.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me. Loop through each sheet (change the `A14`) and color code.

```
    Sub ColorCodeWS()

      ' loop thru each sheet
      For Each ws In Sheets
         ws.Activate

         If Range("A14") > 0 Then
           ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = 3 'red
         ElseIf Range("A14") = 0 Then
           ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = 4 'green
         Else
           ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = xlNone 'no color
         End If
      Next ws    
    End Sub
```

Comment: This code does and is easier than the code I have written but I need it to constantly update. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You do not need to activate each sheet in order to check a range and change the colour based on that. Using `.Activate` is hardly ever needed. Since you are already looping through each sheet, you can use `ws.` instead of `ActiveSheet`. You will also need to fully qualify the `Range...` as `ws.Range...` and you are good to do the same thing, without ever activating the sheets.